# Gitlab CICD Powershell Variables select-string -pattern -AllMatches doesn't count

Tags: powershell, gitlab, yaml, cicd

I want to integrate following working powershell command into Gitlab CICD to test the state of the database:

```
$TestPath = GET-ITEM -PATH "D:\Repos\SQLScripts\testsSingle.sql"|SELECT-OBJECT -EXPANDPROPERTY FULLNAME
echo $TestPath

$output =  sql dbuser/pw@server:1521/DWHI @$TestPath | Out-String 



$amount_passed = select-string -pattern passed -InputObject $output -AllMatches 
$amount_failed = select-string -pattern failed -InputObject $output -AllMatches 
echo $output 

Write-Output "Passed:$($amount_passed.Matches.Length)/$($amount_failed.Matches.Length+$amount_passed.Matches.Length) Failed:$($amount_failed.Matches.Length)/$($amount_failed.Matches.Length+$amount_passed.Matches.Length)"

if ( $amount_failed.Matches.Length -gt 0 ){    exit 1}
```

This translates so far into following pipeline script:

```
.db-test:
    variables:
        CONNECTION_STRING: "$User/$Password@$CONNECTION/$DB_ENV"
        SQL_CL: 'C:\Oracle\sqlcl\bin\sql.exe'
    script:
        - echo $CONNECTION_STRING
        
        - $TestPath = GET-ITEM -PATH ".\SQLScripts\$SqlScript"|SELECT-OBJECT -EXPANDPROPERTY FULLNAME;
        - echo $TestPath

        - $exp = "$SQL_CL $CONNECTION_STRING @$TestPath"
        - echo $exp

        - $output = Invoke-Expression $exp | Out-String
        - echo $output 

        - $amount_passed = "select-string -pattern passed -InputObject $output -AllMatches"
        - echo '$amount_passed' $amount_passed.Matches.Length
```

The result of that ist

```
$ $output = Invoke-Expression $exp | Out-String
$ echo $output

SQLcl: Release 23.1 Production on Thu Jun 22 10:36:10 2023
Copyright (c) 1982, 2023, Oracle.  All rights reserved.
Verbunden mit:
Oracle Database 19c Enterprise Edition Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production
Version 19.18.0.0.0
TEST                           STATUS    
______________________________ _________ 
package                         passed    
table                           failed    
table                           failed    
table                           failed    
Abgemeldet von Oracle Database 19c Enterprise Edition Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production
Version 19.18.0.0.0

$ $amount_passed = select-string -pattern passed -InputObject $output -AllMatches
$ echo '$amount_passed' $amount_passed.Matches.Length
$amount_passed
0
Cleaning up project directory and file based variables
00:01
Job succeeded
```

I expect the `$amount_passed.Matches.Length` to be 1. In Powershell it was working.

I tried it as well like

```
- $amount_passed = select-string -pattern passed -InputObject $output -AllMatches
```

and

```
- $amount_passed = "select-string -pattern passed -InputObject $($output) -AllMatches"
```

Comment: Please, properly [format your question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks)